# Write to iPhone file system - Jailbreak/Toolchain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

so I am working on a jb app that requires writing to the file system (/var/mobile/Library/Downloads specifically), and I tried hard coding it in like someone recommended but I cant seem to make it work, i know how to do so to the Documents directory in my app but not the file system, any ideas? thank you!

edit 1 - as reference: the way that the Safari DL Plugin does it

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path?  Did this fail in the Simulator or on the device?  The Mac has a different filesystem than the iPhone.

Comment: Ya, I mobile term'd it, I tried on the device, the sim one is weird as hell I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this path
/private/var/mobile/Library/Downloads

You need to check if the directory already exists or not before writing to it. You can use NSFileManager class for file/directory operations. You also need to check for the permissions on that folder, your app if not running as root cannot write to folders which only root has access to.